# When I run my selenium scripts through Jenkins, browser was not instantiated in Jenkins server but my Jenkins build was pass

Tags: selenium, jenkins

When I run my selenium scripts through Jenkins, browser was not instantiated in Jenkins server but my Jenkins build was pass. Build should be failed. can you please help me to provide solution on this ?

Comment: Do you have something you can show us? Some configuration maybe?

Comment: Show the job console ouput, you can mask the sensitive information like ip/hostname/file path/git repo etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems you are using windows, "you need to allow Jenkins service to interact with desktop"
 follow below step in order to enable Jenkins service to interact with desktop.

1- open run and search for "services.msc"
2- Scroll down to the Jenkins service and right-click, select Properties.
3- Now click on Log on Tab and you will see "Allow service to interact with desktop" check this checkbox and you are done.
```